# Git - already on branch in commandline, but branch not available in git plug-in for Atom

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a remote branch of my Gitlab project that is active in the terminal. When I run `git checkout branch` it comes back `already on branch`.

However, in the Git tab in Atom, the branch tab only lists three of my current seven branches. In command line, running `git branch -r` returns ten branches, which includes deleted and/or merged branches.

Running `git fetch` returns

```
From gitlab.com:zeesy/project
 * [new branch]      branch        -> origin/branch
```

What is happening here? I'd like to be able to edit my files in Atom, and then push to Git.

Running `git branch -a` returns

```
* branch
  baby-steps-demo
  lit-html-demo
  master
  webapp
  working-demo
  archaeological-record
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/branch
  remotes/origin/archaeological-record
  remotes/origin/baby-steps-demo
  remotes/origin/js
  remotes/origin/lit-html-demo
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/split-pages
  remotes/origin/webapp
  remotes/origin/working-demo
```

note that `baby-steps-demo` no longer exists in the GitLab project.

Running `git pull && git checkout branch` results in

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> branch
```

Which suggests there is no remote branch. However, the branch is completely accessible from Gitlab.

Comment: My guess is that your call to `git fetch` may have already resolved everything.  Can you run `git branch -a` and then share the output from that in your question?

Comment: Thanks, Tim. See above.

Comment: 7. I deleted a line to change names. Will correct in the question.

Comment: Whatever `git branch -a` tells you is reality.  If your editor differs from this, then I think it has some problem.  I do recall from several years ago that the eGit plugin for Eclipse had a handful of known bugs, so there is a precedence for this sort of thing happening.

Comment: Sad for me because I'm used to Atom. Will follow up if the next update fixes or if I find a workaround. Thanks for your time!

Comment: `branch` does exist in remote. The message from `git pull` suggests that your local `branch` does not track `origin/branch`, so git doesn't know to pull from that when you simply run `git pull`.  You want to run the `git branch --set-upstream-to...` command in that message.

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

You may just need to run `git checkout branch` (which I guess you already did) and then restart Atom (kill it off entirely; it tends to keep running so as to start up quickly and open windows easily).  I have not actually used Atom, so this is a guess—its plugin might assume that only the plugin does anything Git-related, so that it never re-scans after you do things in the command line.

A long description of what's actually going on may be helpful here, though.

#### Long

I will talk here about `git fetch` and Git's naming system.

> note that `baby-steps-demo` no longer exists in the GitLab project ...

This is normal enough: by default, `git fetch` won't *remove* remote-tracking names, it will only *create or update* them.

There are several parts here.  You have *your* Git repository, the server has *its* Git repository, and each repository has *its own* branch names.  But your Git repository needs to remember the *other* Git repository's names too.  So your Git repository has, in addition to your (local) branch names, a set of *remote-tracking names* that correspond to what the other Git repository has—or had, the last time your Git talked with their Git.

It may help your visualization of what's going on if you run, from the command line:

```
git ls-remote origin
```

This shows you what the first few steps of `git fetch origin` (or `git fetch` that goes to `origin`) do:

1. Call up the other Git at whatever `git config --get remote.origin.url` says.
2. Get from them a listing of all their *references* (a technical term covering both branches and tag; there are others as well but your Git won't care about anything but their branch and tag names here) and their corresponding hash-ID values.

   For my Git repository for Git, when I run `git ls-remote origin,` the first few lines are:

   ```
   3e5524907b43337e82a24afbc822078daf7a868f        HEAD
   fc54c1af3ec09bab8b8ea09768c2da4069b7f53e        refs/heads/maint
   3e5524907b43337e82a24afbc822078daf7a868f        refs/heads/master
   61856ae69a2ceb241a90e47953e18f218e4d5f2f        refs/heads/next
   ```

   for instance.

Once your `git fetch` has this information, it determines which branches it wants to bring over (their `maint`, `master`, and so on—their branches) so it checks to see if you have commits `fc54c1a...`, `3e55249...`, and so on.

Whatever commits you *don't* have, your Git asks their Git for, along with any other objects needed to complete your repository.  This all happens in a fairly swift "I have X, but I need Y" exchange, after which their Git builds a *pack file* to send you:

```
remote: counting objects ...
remote: compressing objects ...
```

Once they've sent you everything, *your* Git squirrels these objects away, indexed by their hash IDs, in your database.  Unless you (or your Git, really) throw them away at some point, now that you have these objects, you never need to retrieve them again.

Finally, your Git has to set up some *name or names* by which to *remember* these objects, or more specifically, their hash IDs.  If your Git doesn't know why it has these objects—if it does not have a name by which it can find them—it will eventually throw them away.  One place it stores the hash IDs is the special `FETCH_HEAD` file.  Each new fetch overwrites that file with whatever it fetched, so that what you got at least sticks around until the next `git fetch`.  But the more important one for your purposes here—because it lasts much longer—is that your Git *renames* their branch names:

- `refs/heads/master` becomes `refs/remotes/origin/master`
- `refs/heads/next` becomes `refs/remotes/origin/next`

Your Git then creates or updates the name on the right side of this set.  These are your *remote-tracking names*.

For display purposes Git *shortens* these, though, dropping at least `refs/` and usually the next slash-separated word as well.  The `git fetch` command prefixes all of this with abbreviated hash IDs:

```
   aaaaaaa..bbbbbbb  master        -> origin/master
```

which tells you that your Git updated *your* `refs/remotes/origin/master` based on *their* `refs/heads/master`, and at the same time, that *your* `refs/remotes/origin/master` *used to* name commit `aaaaaaa` and now names commit `bbbbbbb` instead.  Or:

```
 * [new branch]      branch        -> origin/branch
```

which tells you that your Git *created* your `refs/remotes/origin/branch` just now, based on seeing `refs/heads/branch` in the `git ls-remote` listing.

Note that your `origin/baby-steps-demo`—the full name is really `refs/remotes/origin/baby-steps-demo`; it's just shortened for display—is your *remote-tracking name*, not a *branch* name.<sup>1</sup>  A branch name is a name whose full version starts with `refs/heads/`.

Now we can come back to this remark:

> note that `baby-steps-demo` no longer exists in the GitLab project ...

This means that when your Git calls up their Git, they *don't* list a `refs/heads/baby-steps-demo`.

Your Git used their `baby-steps-demo` to create your `origin/baby-steps-demo`.  Should your Git now remove your `origin/baby-steps-demo`?  If you would like your Git to, you can tell your Git to use their full list of all their branches to *prune* your remote-tracking names.  You can do this with `git fetch --prune`, or set `fetch.prune` to `true` in your Git configuration to make `git fetch` do this by default.

The command-line command `git branch -r` shows specifically and only these remote-tracking names.

The command-line command `git branch` (without `-r`) shows specifically and only *your* branch names.  These don't depend on the existence of remote-tracking names (nor vice versa).

Every (local) branch can have one, but only one, *upstream*.  The upstream for a branch like `master` that you create based on a remote-tracking name like `origin/master` will typically have the remote-tracking name set as its upstream, but that's something you may have to tell Git to set, depending on precisely how you created the (local) branch name.

Some operations, including `git pull`, use the upstream setting to determine what to `git fetch`, and what to `git merge` once the `git fetch` finishes.  If your branch does not have an upstream set, they can't or won't assume some default.

In your case, your current branch `branch` does not have `origin/branch` set as its upstream (as it has no upstream set at all).  If you run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/branch branch
```

you will tell your Git to set `origin/branch` as the upstream for your branch named `branch`.  If it had some other upstream setting before this, that would replace the old upstream setting with this new one.

The upstream setting is really just a pair of names; `git branch --set-upstream-to` makes sure the names exist and are valid, and then sets them, and `git branch --unset-upstream` removes them entirely (so that a branch has no upstream any more, if you want to do that for whatever reason).

---

<sup>1</sup>This set of phrases clearly leaves a lot to be desired.  If a branch is something you can get "onto" using `git checkout`, then a *remote-tracking name* or *remote-tracking branch name* isn't a branch, because `git checkout origin/master` or similar leaves you in *detached HEAD* mode.  Moreover, a *remote-tracking (branch) name* is actually something your own Git stores locally!  But some people like to think of remote-tracking names as branch names, and they do have "branch-y" behavior.